# Should the access review queues button be visible to users with less than 500 reputation?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, top-bar

I have recently noticed, that in the top bar there is a button that says `Review queues` and takes me to `/review`. I thought that meant I now have enough reputation to access the review queues, but upon clicking on it, I was greeted by a completely grayed out list. I personally find this slightly distracting and confusing. Shouldn't the button be hidden from users with less than the required 500 reputation?

Comment: Users are able to review suggested edits on their own posts at any reputation. Also, why not allow users to discover the feature early?

Comment: @MartijnPieters In one of the older versions I found out about it through the reputation FAQ, which I can't find anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this didn't make a lot of sense. Heck, arguably putting the review privilege for Docs at 100 doesn't make a ton of sense either, but there were good reasons to do that... Still, they don't warrant such a major disruption to the top bar for folks who can't do much in review just yet.

So, we removed the review icon until the Access Review Queues privilege is earned. See: [Where did the Review Icon go?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345742/where-did-the-review-icon-go)

Answer (score 1):

There is a one more queue which is opened at 100 rep which is [Documentation review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing) is present at bottom of all review queues which you might overlooked. I have sufficient rep so I am unable to tell that all users are showing review icon or not, but you are certainly able to view Documentation review queue which might be a reason.

Comment: For me it's at the top, but I missed it, because it has 0 entries.