# Where did the Review Icon go?

Tags: support, top-bar

There used to be an icon on the top-right of the main page for reviewing. If you click it presents all the review queues. I don't see it anymore. Why?

*edit*

[image: Top bar]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce in Chrome 57 on Windows 10.

Comment: @yellowantphil They can still review documentation changes. That only takes 100 rep. Still, don't know if they would have had access to that icon either way...

Comment: So, I'm with Mike- The review icon is there (and working) for me. Was the last time you saw it _before_ or _after_ the top bar changed? If before, then you just don't know what the new icon is. If after... No idea.

Comment: After the change. On march 3 I used it.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Any plugins/extensions installed? If yes, have you tried disabling these or using incognito/private browsing?

Comment: Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m. Nothing new installed. Win 10

Comment: Maybe share a screenshot of what you see? You are still on Stack Overflow, right? Not on Reddit, Quora or one of the sites that still have the old top-bar?

Comment: It looks like you're in an A/B test. The help icon replaced access to the review queue. Maybe that is now in the hamburger menu?

Comment: The (?) menu should contain the review link in that design.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a recent change - the review icon shows up for people who have the [Access Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege. Users without this privilege see the help icon and menu.

The community team have decided that it is better to show the help link prominently to users with lower reputation than those with higher.

The documentation team was consulted about this change and given that most links to the documentation review queue are from documentation itself, they were happy with this change.

Comment: The OP can test this now as I just put them over 500 rep ...

Comment: What, you don't trust me, @rene ? I am hurt :(

Comment: I wish the review icon for +500 was simply inside of the help icon menu.

Comment: @TravisJ - we have plans for the review icon.

Comment: @Oded - Yay! :D

Comment: @TravisJ - you say that now, before you've seen the changes...

Comment: @Oded - Progress is progress. At least change is being made, because in my opinion the current review icon is problematic (as I have posted in several places, including here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343663/1026459). While a change may not turn out to be perfect, or it could be amazing, it would have been discouraging to have heard that no change whatsoever was planned. I tend to be an optimist though, so I am planning on changes happening, and them being amazing ;)

Comment: What about reviewing document changes is that still possible with 100 reps?

Comment: @Mot - yes, those with 100 rep can still review documentation. This is just a change to the link in the nav bar.

Comment: what's these plans for the review icon? I'm desperate to stop seeing the count number. I don't review things, don't plan on it. sorry.